# Is a function like $f(x) = \frac{2^x - 1}{x}$ continuous?

Tags: calculus

Its plot shows that it's continuous, but the function doesn't have a value at $x=0$, is that right? If not, is it still a continuous function?

[image]

Comment: It's undefined at 0

Comment: It is continuous on its domain, which consists of two disjoint intervals. Just saying a function is continuous is meaningless.

Comment: You can make the function continous on $\mathbb R$ by adding the point $(0/\ln(2))$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $$f(x) = \frac{2^x - 1}{x}$$ is continuous in all the domain of definition that is $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Since for $x=0$ the limit exists finite we can define $$f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=\ln 2$$ and by this extension $f(x)$ becomes continuous for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

Graphs are not always a reliable indicator of the behaviour of functions. Indeed, some functions simply cannot be graphed.

The function $$\frac{2^x-1}{x}$$ has a singularity at $x=0$ (think of this as a hole on its graph). However, we can make it have a value by defining its value to be some suitable number of our choice (in general, this makes the function discontinuous at that point). Usually, though, when the limit exists at that point, it is desirable to define its value there to be the limit, so that it is also continuous there.

Answer (score -1):

$f(0)$ is the derivative of $2^x$ at $0$. You can extend it continuously at $0$.

Comment: No. $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ is the derivative of $2^x$ at $0$. $f(0)$ does not exist, that the whole point ($f$ is not defined at $0$: writing $f(0)$ is like writing $f(\text{watermelon})$), but $f$ can be *extended* to a different function $g$ by continuity.